# Getting web driver logging information running Protractor

Tags: testing, webdriver, protractor

So I am in the process of writing some tests with Protractor for an angular application I am working on.  I ran into an issue where a test was failing because I tried to click on an element that while existed, it could not be clicked because another element was above it and it was receiving the click event.  The error was just that `true` not does equal `false` which gives no insight to the real underlaying issue.  I have run into this issue many times with other tests so I knew pretty quickly was the issue was but if I had not experienced this before, I don't know how long it would take me to figure it out.

I am 99% sure that when you send a click event with the JSON Wire Protocol that if the element does receive the click, there will be a message relating to that in it's response.  Is there any way with Protractor to get the JSON Wire Protocol responses on to the screen when running the tests or at least get the responses captured in a file or something?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Jasmine (the default) i suggest you start using explicit waits for elements to be present and visible **before** interacting with them like in your example.

I'm using [this custom mathers](https://gist.github.com/elgalu/cdab6850800483b244e5).

Then:

```
var theElementFinder = $('#someElm');
expect(theElementFinder).toBePresentAndDisplayed();
```

Regarding

> a way with Protractor to get the JSON Wire Protocol responses

You already see selenium errors in your Terminal / Console output.